# randomly remove portions of a sequence to create shorter sequence

Tags: python, perl, random, cut, sequences

I am new to programming and would appreciate your help!

I have a file with ~20K sequences with the following format:

```
>sequence_1
MAADTPGKPSASPMAGAPASASRTPDKPRSAAEHRKSSKPVMEKRRRARINESLAQLKTLILDALRKESSRHSKLEKADILEMTVRHLRSLRRVQVTAALSADPAVLGKYRAGFHECLAEVNRFLAGCEGVPADVRSRLLGHLAACLRQLGPSRRPASLSPAAPAEAPAPEVYAGRPLLPSLGGPFPLLAPPLLPGLTRALPAAPRAGPQGPGGPWRPWLR

>sequence_2
MGWDLTVKMLAGNEFQVSLSSSMSVSELKAQITQKIGVHAFQQRLAVHPSGVALQDRVPLASQGLGPGSTVLLVVDKCDEPLSILVRNNKGRSSTYEVRLTQTVAHLKQQVSGLEGVQDDLFWLTFEGKPLEDQLPLGEYGLKPLSTVFMNLRLRGGGTEPGGRS
```

I want to create random fragments of these sequences of lengths ~ 50-100 characters. I need to keep the original order intact (so I am not randomizing the characters).

Examples of sequences I could make from >sequence_1 would be:

```
MAADTPGKPSASPMAGAPASASRTPDKPRSAAEHRKSSKPVMEKRRRARINESLAQLKTLILDALR
```

or

```
MTVRHLRSLRRVQVTAALSADPAVLGKYRAGFHECLAEVNRFLAGCEGVPADVRSRLLGHLAACLRQLGPSRRPASLSPAAPAEAPAPEVYAGRPLLPSLGGPFPLLAPPLLPGLTRALPAAPRAGPQGPGGPW
```

The best analogy I can think of is randomly cutting these sequences into smaller lengths. I'm really unsure how to even go about this, or if it is possible with a script. I'd also appreciate any explanation for responses so I can learn.

Comment: I don't know enough about coding yet to even try anything. I am completely lost about how to approach this problem. Sorry.

Comment: So what exactly do you want? One random subsequence from each original sequence? Or more? What output format do you want? Your input looks like FASTA; do you want the output to be the same, or is just one sequence per line okay? Are the starting positions and lengths to be evenly distributed, or do you want something else?

Comment: @Borodin, it can be one or more random subsequences from each original sequence, so whichever is easier. Yes, fasta output would be ideal. The starting positions and lengths do not necessarily have to be evenly distributed, so again, however it is easiest to write a script. The biggest constraint is that the sequences need to be between 50-100 amino acids (or characters) in length. Also, if possibly, it would be ideal that the script would generate new random sequences each time it was run. Thanks so much.

Comment: I think there must still be more to your requirement. You haven't described anything that can't be solved by just printing the first fifty characters of each sequence.

Comment: @Borodin, well I do want to randomize it. I want to be able to run the script multiple times with a different output each time (I need multiple trials to compare). So the starting position should vary. Does this give enough information? I'm not sure what else I am leaving out.

Answer (score 0):

Use a randomly generated start for a slice:

```
from random import *

def fifty_slice(sequence):
    i = randrange(0, len(sequence) - 50)
    return sequence[i:i+50]
```

Comment: I tried to save that as a script and run it on the original file, but it created a binary file for the output. I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.

Comment: Just place this in your main file and pass the sequences as arguments.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are after implementing a tree data structure in python.

Each line of your 20 K sequences each are parent nodes, and then you can create code that creates children for each of the random sub sequences. Each of the children can also become parents if needed, though I don't think the problem you described requires this.

see https://github.com/caesar0301/treelib